# Parse user input for command arguments into array

Tags: php-7

I'm making a bot in PHP and I want a better way to parse user input into arguments for later operations.

An example would be a user saying "/addresponse -"test" -"works""

I want this to parse that string into:

```
$command ["test", "works"];
```

I have found the PHP command parser but I want the user to be able to use human readable commands rather than typing something like /addresponse?p="test"&r="works"

Right now I have a regex working so the user can type "/addresponse "test" "works"" but there are obvious problems because the user cannot make a response for '"test"' only 'test'

I'd appreciate any help, right now I think I can make a regex to get all text between ' -' but I still don't think this is the best solution.

I just looked into using a regex to find text between ' -"' and while this is better than just between quotes, it doesn't solve the whole problem because it still will break if the input contains ' -"'.  A string containing this isn't particularly common but I'd like a solution where almost any input will not break it.

Is this a stupid question? I don't think there is a built in php function for this and it got downvoted with no comment...

Comment: Not a PHP7-specific question. You should tag it [tag:php] and maybe [tag:regex] but, most important, you should post some code. [so] is about code, not about literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution:

```
function parse_cmd($command) {
        $command = explode(' -"', $command);
        array_splice($command, 0, 1);
        foreach($command as &$element) {
                $element = substr($element, 0, strlen($element) -1);
        }
        return $command;
}
```

This will split everything after ' -"' and return it as an array